# bash not taking variable declaration

Tags: bash, variables, assignment-operator

I am trying to pass a list to a variable using reference inside a function in bash however the interpreter is reading the variable assignment as a command.
Please help me to understand what I am doing wrong.

I looked for possible spaces between the equal sign but the debugger (`bash -x`) is showing no spaces

```
#!/bin/bash

parseNmerge () {
        for a in $( echo ${!2} )
        do
                str=$(echo $a|awk -F\# '{print $1"#"$2"#"$3"#"$4"#"$5"#"$6"#"$7"#"}')
                #declare "${1}"="$(echo "${!1}" |grep -v $str)"
                #declare "${1}"="$(echo -e "${!1}\n$a")"
                "${1}"="$(echo "${!1}" |grep -v $str)"
                "${1}"="$(echo -n "${!1}\n$a")"
        done
}

a_cmp=$(grep -v ^# param.cfg.2)
a_all=$(grep -v ^# param.cfg.1)

parseNmerge "a_all" "a_cmp"

for b in $a_all
do
        echo $b
done
```

when running the script I get the following complain:

```
$ ./xx
./xx: line 9: a_all=NAME#ALL#ALL#PROD#0#START#maximumpain#4
DEFAULT#TID#ALL#DEF#0#START#zarea#20000000: command not found
```

The content of the test files are:

```
$ cat param.cfg.1

NAME#ALL#ALL#PROD#0#START#threadcount#1
NAME#ALL#ALL#PROD#0#START#maximumpain#4
\#NAME#ALL#ALL#DEVR#0#START#threadcount#7
DEFAULT#TID#ALL#DEF#0#START#zarea#20000000

$ cat param.cfg.2

NAME#ALL#ALL#PROD#0#START#threadcount#4
DEFAULT#TID#ALL#DEF#0#START#zarea#20000001
```

PS: When using `declare` it works however using `declare` inside the function makes the result set not available outside the function
PS: The script runs fine when not using reference
e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

parseNmerge () {
        for a in $(echo $a_cmp)
        do
                str=$(echo $a|awk -F\# '{print $1"#"$2"#"$3"#"$4"#"$5"#"$6"#"$7"#"}')
                a_all=$(echo "$a_all"|grep -v "$str")
                a_all=$(echo -e "$a_all\n$a")
        done
}


a_cmp=$(grep -v ^# param.cfg.2)
a_all=$(grep -v ^# param.cfg.1)

parseNmerge

for b in $(echo $a_all)
do
        echo $b
done
```

Comment: If you're using Bash≥4.2, use `declare -g`. Otherwise, you'll have to use `eval`… but since you're using lots of wrong constructs and antipatterns all over the place, I guess you're not really familiar with shell scripting, so I wouldn't recommend that (no offense).

Comment: Not taken... I see an opportunity to learn here
Can you give me some tips about wrong constructs and antipatterns in this context?

Comment: Lots of quotes missing, bad choice of variable types (you're using strings where you should use arrays), useless uses of subshells, `echo` and `awk`, etc. Too many wrong conceptions to fit in this comment; that would be more appropriate for a code review site. In fact, what you're trying to achieve with this code is not even clear to me. Can you describe your _task_ and not the problem you're encountering when you're trying to achieve your task using what you _think_ is appropriate? we're clearly having an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: @DanR. This is an interesting question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72153286/javascript-the-definitive-guide-4-7-6-order-of-evaluation are you interested in an answer?